# How to set the encoding of a SSIS "Script task" file of a Visual Studio 2008 SSIS project

Tags: encoding, ssis

In My SSIS script task I need to refer to ressources (eg. database tables) that contain special european characters. How do I force my script file (C# code) to be stored using another encoding such as UTF-8.

At the moment I have to escaping the characters using \uXXX which is near unreadable.

Comment: I'm not sure how many resources you'd need to define, but what if you "cheat?" Create SSIS variables which are unicode strings, store your accented data in those and reference those in your script. It's a bit unwieldy, I admit, but it should avoid the need to use unicode escapes in your scripting.

Comment: I'd rather just change the encoding of the script. It gets inlined in the xml document (the *.dtsx file).

Comment: What does it take to reproduce your issue? I'm a "dumb American" and not familiar with the intricacies of internationalization. Would `string utf8= "";` suffice assuming I had some "weird" character in there?

Answer (score 2):

While I'm waiting on a repro, how I *think* you would accomplish this is the same manner you would use to save any file out with encoding in VS/SSMS

I added some arabic looking text in there, assuming that would qualify as UTF-8

[image: File, Save As]

[image: Save As]

[image: Encoding]

Closing and re-opening the script task retains the script.

Comment: Nice suggestion! However, it only works the first time you use it. If you close the application and re-open the encoding is gone.

Comment: It works for me. my ÅØÆ characters got changed to ? when saving my C# script task. Using bilinkc method they are kept.